# How do I get rid of the Navigation bar in Bing Maps?

Tags: bing-maps

How do I get rid of the navigation bar at the top of Bing Maps? The bar has Road and Automatic selectors as well as Bird's Eye and Aerial selectors. [image: What I want to get rid of]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Themes.BingTheme', { callback: function() 
{
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('SDKmap'), 
    { 
         credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key', 
         theme: new Microsoft.Maps.Themes.BingTheme(),
         showMapTypeSelector:false
    }); 
}});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me... Setting "showMapTypeSelector:false" will turn off not only the top bar selector but also the other map controls (zoom, directions, etc)...

Comment: I think that these questions are related. Possible other fix here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546192/bing-maps-v7-not-showing-navigation-bar