# Bing Maps v7 not showing navigation bar

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I am using a Bing Maps v7 Ajax Control, but can't see the navigation bar with the zoom tools even when setting `showDashboard:true`. It seems to only be the case when the following setting is also set: `showMapTypeSelector: false`.

Answer (score 2):

This was because the `showMapTypeSelector` applies a class called `hidden` to the navigation bar `div`. Unfortunately I also use Twitter Bootstrap which also has a class named `hidden` which of course hides the `div`!

Fixed it with a little dirty css hack as follows:

```
#SDKmap .hidden {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Where `SDKmap` is the map element ID.